# What is evaluation metric for two sets?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluations, performance, metric, f1score

I've two sets one is ground truth and other is output of my machine learning models. Assume my groundtruth set is *A={1,2,3,4,5}* and output of machine learning model is *B={3,4,5,6,7,8}*. One way I can measure performance is **IoU(Inersection over union)** like object detection. So IoU will be

> A intersecton B/ A U B

I'm not sure is it reasonable? Or any other better **evaluation metric** can I use to measure the performance?

Answer (score 1):

"I'm not sure is it reasonable?"

yes it is. The metric you refer to is known as the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Comment: Is there any evaluation metric?

Comment: there are other metrics you can think of, for instance a variation of the Jaccard index called overlap coefficient, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap_coefficient.  But at the end you should think which metric aligns which your goals.